# Unable to use qiskit_textbook module

Tags: qiskit, programming, textbook-and-exercises

When I tried to use the Qiskit textbook module, it threw the following error:

Command was:

```
from qiskit_textbook.tools import array_to_latex
array_to_latex(final_state, pretext="\\text{Statevector} = ")
```

Error was:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-fe86c66f7ae0> in <module>
----> 1 from qiskit_textbook.tools import array_to_latex
      2 array_to_latex(final_state, pretext="\\text{Statevector} = ")

ModuleNotFoundError: **No module named 'qiskit_textbook'**
```

When I looked up the version I had, it showed the following:

```
{'qiskit-terra': '0.12.0',
 'qiskit-aer': '0.4.1',
 'qiskit-ignis': '0.2.0',
 'qiskit-ibmq-provider': '0.5.0',
 'qiskit-aqua': '0.6.4',
 'qiskit': '0.16.1'}
```

**Can someone help me in resolving the issue?**

Comment: `pip install git+https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-textbook.git#subdirectory=qiskit-textbook-src`

Answer (score 4):

**Use this command to install qiskit-textbook module**

```
pip install git+https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-textbook.git#subdirectory=qiskit-textbook-src
```

Answer (score 3):

The qiskit textbook is not a standard module included with qiskit, it has to be installed separately. The repo where it is kept is [here](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-textbook). [This link](https://adamj.eu/tech/2019/03/11/pip-install-from-a-git-repository/) explains how to pip install from a git repo, you need to use a slightly different command to normal pip installs.